# C# New process window does not hide

Tags: c#, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide Command Window in C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440105/hide-command-window-in-c-sharp-application)

in the console app, I want to run the cmd command, but a new window is being created, why ?

```
 Process process = new Process();
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\m_f";
 startInfo.Arguments = "/c START _creator.bat";
 process.StartInfo = startInfo;
 process.Start();
```

### edit

I had to change some code to:

```
 startInfo.FileName = @"C:\m_f\_creator.bat";
 startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\m_f\";
 startInfo.Arguments = "some_args";
```

now it works

Comment: console app is not the same as the command prompt(cmd.exe) which you start here as external process.

Comment: Your problem is START, remove it.

Comment: You got it yourself! The window isn't cmd.exe, it's the program started by cmd.exe. So you start the program itself to hide it.

Comment: The other option is to pass /B as an option to `START` - that will run the command without creating another window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start` spawns a new window, regardless of whether the parent shell has a window or not.

To run a batch file `cmd /c foo.cmd` suffices, or even `foo.cmd`.

Comment: While `foo.cmd` is a better idea, you can pass the `/B` option to `start` to not create a new window, as noted in my comment above.